# can imacros fetch code from raw pastebin?

Tags: javascript, imacros

how to make the code in pastebin read in imacros

> `src="https://pastebin.com/raw/bdyhnk7s"`

I've tried using this and some other sources but it still fails, can imacros javascript not run online?

Comment: (-1) from me for the "superb" Low Quality of your Qt...! Read my Profile on how to ask Qt's about the [tag:imacros] Tag "a bit correctly", + your Qt has nothing related to the [tag:js] Tag... But I still posted an Answer to your Qt...

Comment: "An Answer", => sorry, I meant: "THE Answer"...!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES...!

(Tested on iMacros for FF v8.8.2, PM v26.3.3, Win10_x64.)